# Writing a bash script to run a matlab program in UNIX?

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, unix

I have no bash scripting background. I know the basics of unix command line.

I have a matlab script that takes in an matrix image as input. I have a bunch of images in a file. I need the bash script to call the matlab program and feed every single image in the file as input to the program one by one.

If you want to write it go ahead that would be great. All I'm asking is for someone to direct me to exactly what I should look into.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that the `matlab` command is in your path (for more info, [See the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html) )

Supposing you just wanted to get all of the BMP's (you didn't specify file type), you can use a simple bash loop:

```
for f in *.BMP; do
    matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nojvm -r "my_command('$f'),quit()"
done
```

The `-nosplash`, `-nodisplay`, and `-nojvm` ensure that the GUI isn't triggered, and the `-r` instructs matlab to run the command.  The `,quit()` at the end ensures that matlab quits after running.

Answer (score 1):

You need

- one command what produces list of images one per line. Call it as `list_images`, or a `filename` what contains the list of images
- one cycle
- command, what reads the images
- one variable (calling it "image_name")
- comamnd to run matlab
- place, here the output should go

Something like:

```
list_images | while read image_name
do
     matlab_command "$image_name" > "$image_name.output"
done
```

or better

```
while read image_name
do
    matlab_command "$image_name" > "$image_name.output"
done < filename_with_images.txt
```

Not really understand what you mean with the `have amatrix images in a file`, post an example of your input.

**EDIT** for finding `prj` files in the curent directory

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -name \*.prj -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' image_name
do
    matlab_command "$image_name" > "$image_name.output"
done
```

Google for "bash tutorial".

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. The input files are in .prj format. I have them all stored in a directory. I really just need the script to pass in the file names as a parameter to my matlab function. In your answer above, I'm not understanding where you actually read the file names from the directory.